# Emacs hexl-mode UTF8 BOM issue

Tags: emacs, utf-8

I ran into something a bit weird with the *hexl-mode* under Emacs (GNU Emacs 22.2.1 / Debian GNU Linux).

I had an UTF8 text file to which I wanted to append a BOM (Byte Order Mask: even though it is not recommended to append a pointless BOM to an UTF8 file, the spec clearly specify that a BOM in an UTF8 file **is** legal).

Here's how the file is seen by the *file* command:

```
...$  file  /tmp/test.txt
/tmp/test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode English text
```

The following works:

```
open the UTF8 file (without BOM) in text mode
add three ASCII characters at the beginning of the file
close the file   (<-- see, very important, I need to close the file)
M-x hexl-mode
M-x hexl-find-file  (re-opening the file but this time in hexl-mode)
M-x hexl-insert-hex-string
EFBBBF
C-x C-s (saving the file)
M-x hexl-mode-exit
```

I then get an UTF-8 file with a BOM, as shown here by the *file* command:

```
...$  file  /tmp/test.txt
/tmp/test.txt: UTF-8 Unicode (with BOM) English text
```

*(note that the file command detects this heuristically as an UTF-8 with BOM "English text" but the file does contain a lot of Euro symbol: my point is that, before adding the BOM, it is NOT an ASCII file but already an UTF-8 file, as shown above)*

However I simply cannot open the file under Emacs **first** then call *hexl-mode* then try to replace the first three characters by 0xEB 0xFF 0xBF (the BOM) and then save.

Apparently there are crazy conversion issues taking place when switching from *(Text)* to *(Hexl)* mode.

Am I missing something obvious or is converting to/from Text / Hexl a bit broken and I'm better to switch to *hexl-mode* first, do my hex editing then save & close the file and re-open in text mode?

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/41254/make-emacs-not-remove-the-bom-from-xml-files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you take a look on `hexl-find-file` code you will see that it calls `find-file-literally` and then switch to the `hexl-mode`.

From the documentation of `find-file-literally`

> Visit file FILENAME with no conversion of any kind. Format conversion
>   and character code conversion are both disabled,and multibyte
>   characters are disabled in the resulting buffer.

So you may open your file with `find-file-literally` add 3 characters and then switch to the `hexl-mode`.

Answer (score 0):

Note that an xml file with this tag will be silently converted to utf-16 big endian on saving.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

This would automatically make the file utf8 with bom after changing and saving it:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```